# Convert an array of object to antd table columns?

Tags: javascript, arrays, antd

I have an array of object and i need to convert that into antd table columns format. Here is the [online editor link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkDsAcFcBcBQBjA9pAzvUBDUBeUAbUVDNAG9TyaBLAEwC5QBGAGmprKxwCd4AajgA2sAKbN2nLmMj0hoiaADMHLuQBGqAB7MARGOFi9a8gF9TZKurINmAJktce-BeOarpNWfJHvQAKxONFq6oHoAbsiwJtIW0tY2dirB5C6CfkqOXuQ+bkoAbKlkofoAttGxNPEAuoiIIKCoCHBIDWAkjTRUXTb0OPA4tHJiYQwcveoA1mIAnszj7TZk8LTwRgv0E2DV21w9O30DQyNh6fl7yzPzoOeZlzar60p3ig9k8ZOUS8v9g8P0UbMPL3H42a7AuQXMHqJ4bUAgt4w0CfQ5WZE0P4nQFhULvLgQ0B4jHkOFKYlfVGgOqIIA).

```js
const a = [
    {
        id: 1,
        startValue: 1,
        endValue: 3,
        box: "ele",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        startValue: 3,
        endValue: 5,
        box: "vcu",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        startValue: 2,
        endValue: 6,
        box: "mcu",
    },
]

// output

// [
//     {
//         dataindex: id,
//         key: id,
//         title: id,
//     },
//     {
//         dataindex: startValue,
//         key: startValue,
//         title: startValue,
//     },
//     {
//         dataindex: endValue,
//         key: endValue,
//         title: endValue,
//     },
//     {
//         dataindex: box,
//         key: box,
//         title: box,
//     },
// ]
```

Comment: Your `output` array does not seem to make much sense. Do you want to produce this structure for each of the objects in the input array `a`? Or did you maybe intend to create an HTML-table-string out of the input array?

Comment: I have to create the antd Table, table accepts columns in the format as mentioned in the output.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know about Ant design before and thought "antd" was just a typo in you heading! :D

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you provided, I guess you are trying to automatically extract the column names from the given dataSource. Here is what you are looking for (I reused the variable named `a` :

```
const columns = Object.keys(a[0]||{})
    .map(key => ({dataIndex: key, key, title: key}));

<Table dataSource={a} columns={columns} />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is little to do to achieve what you want. According to [Ant Design documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/?locale=en-US) your data does not need to be converted into `output`. It can directly be used as the `dataSource` array. And you will need to supply the `columns` array as shown below:

```js
const dataSource = [
    {
        id: 1,
        startValue: 1,
        endValue: 3,
        box: "ele",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        startValue: 3,
        endValue: 5,
        box: "vcu",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        startValue: 2,
        endValue: 6,
        box: "mcu",
    }
];

const columns=

[
    {
       dataindex: "id",
       key: "id",
       title: "Id"
    },
    {
       dataindex: "startValue",
       key: "startValue",
       title: "Start value"
    },
    {
       dataindex: "endValue",
       key: "endValue",
       title: "End value"
    },
    {
       dataindex: "box",
       key: "box",
       title: "Box"
    }
   ];

// the following JSX expression will create the ant table in a React environment:
<Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
```

With the `columns` array you define which property of the `dataSource` elements you want to display in the table. The `title` property defines the title to be shown in each column header.

Comment: for that i need to change the array of object to colums array as, so that it can read the title.

Comment: Have you tried the above script? I have no experience with react but expect some table to show up as a result.